# Interface, Inheritance, and C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm designing a data layer for several classes, and I want each of these classes to follow a contract I set up with `IMyDataItem`:

```
public delegate void ItemChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public interface IMyDataItem<T> {
  string Insert { get; }
  int Save();
  string Select { get; }
  string Update { get; }
}
```

That being done, I now want to include a base class that my other classes all inherit from.

How would I fix this **base class**?

```
public class MyDataItem : IMyDataItem<T> {

  private const string TODO = "TODO: This has not been done.";
  public const int NOT_SET = -1;

  private bool changed;
  internal int rowId;

  public MyDataItem() {
    changed = false;
    rowId = NOT_SET;
  }

  public ItemChangedHandler OnChange;

  internal void notify() {
    changed = true;
    if (OnChange != null) {
      OnChange(this, new EventArgs());
    }
  }

  public int RowID {
    get { return rowId; }
    set {
      if (rowId != value) {
        rowId = value;
        notify();
      }
    }
  }

  public bool SaveNeeded { get { return changed; } }

  public static virtual T Load() {
    return default(T);
  }

  public virtual string Insert { get { return TODO; } }

  public virtual string Select { get { return TODO; } }

  public virtual string Update { get { return TODO; } }

  public virtual int Save() {
    changed = false;
    return NOT_SET;
  }
}
```

The errors are all in the second class `MyDataItem` (my base class):

- Type or namespace name 'T' could not be found - on the first line where I declare my class.

I tried removing the errors by adding a `where` clause to the signature:

```
public class MyDataItem : IMyDataItem<T> where T : MyDataItem {
```

However, this presented me with the error:

- Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations

Is there a way to do what I am after, or will I need to stick with simpler class designs?

When the base class is complete, other classes such as **Location**, **Employee**, and **Record** will inherit it.

Comment: Such a large question for such a simple answer.

Comment: And still devdigital says he needs more information.

Comment: Well, it is odd that you have declared a generic interface that doesn't apparently need to be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not drop the `<T>` from the interface and make it non-generic? The `T` is not used in the interface.

Otherwise, if you want the class to be generic, say

```
public class MyDataItem<T> : IMyDataItem<T>
```

But again, if `T` is not used, what's your reason to declare it?

Comment: My static `Load` command needs to know what type to return. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Your static method cannot be declared virtual. You could make the class generic (`class MyDataItem<T>`), or you could make the method generic `public static T Load<T>() { ... }`.

Comment: I'm just noticing that, Jeppe. If I used `public static T Load<T>()`, would I be able to populate the data for different types?

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to use it. Right now, it just returns `default(T)` (which typically means zero for value types, and is just `null` for reference types), and that does not seem useful. Maybe you want it to be an instance method (remove `static`)? Then it can be marked `virtual` (or even `abstract` if you make the class `abstract`).

Comment: I want `Load` to be a "factory" (is that the right word?) for my class. So for class `Company`, I could say `var company = Company.Load(companyID);`

Comment: Similarly, for class `Employee`, I will (under the contract) write `var employee = Employee.Load(employeeID);` I could declare `object Load`, but then I would have to cast everything.

Comment: @jp2code I don't see `Load` taking an ID as paramter? But worse, I don't think a static method can use polymorphism like that. For the same reason a static method can't be virtual. Maybe it's easier to just use a normal instance constructor in each case?

Comment: Thanks Jeppe. The class is currently being written, so the ID parameter being left out was an error from copy-n-paste. Looks like this will have to come out of my OOD efforts. :(

Comment: To answer your earlier question. If `Load` had the declaration `public static T Load<T>()`, then it could be used like `var employee = MyDataItem.Load<Employee>();`. But if `Company` derives from `MyDayaItem`, because static methods are not polymorphic, one could also say `var employee = Company.Load<Employee>();` and that would be confusing?

Answer (score 4):

Well to fix that particularly compile time error you would need:

```
public class MyDataItem<T> : IMyDataItem<T>
```

However, without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to recommend an alternative approach.

Comment: My other classes that are going to Inherit from this base class will have some of the code already written. This design is to ensure I don't forget a step and that I use the same language (or coding terms) throughout my code.

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is somewhat similar to what I've also done.  I've wanted some generic code applicable to all my "data manager" instances but also wanted to apply stronger typing to them...  In a similar fashion...

```
public interface iMyDataManager
{  
   stuff ... 
}

public class MyDataManager<T> : iMyDataManager
{  
   implementation ... that I want common to all derived specific instances 
}


public class MySpecificDataInstance : MyDataManager<MySpecificDataInstance>
{
   continue with rest of actual implementations specific to this class.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing. It never makes sense to me when I read an example full of `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any reason use generic in your implementation.
Secondary, are you sure about parameters of these functions:

```
  string Insert { get; }
  int Save();
  string Select { get; }
  string Update { get; }
```

Why Update and Insert returns parameters? Are you sure, you will able remember meaning of this within 2 months?